# How to wish someone for the upcoming weekend

Tags: word-choice

Is it correct to say "Wish you a happy weekend" or should I say "Wishing you a happy weekend"?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Neither *Wishing you a happy weekend* nor *Wish you a happy weekend* would be used in normal conversation. As others have noted, spoken parting platitudes at the end of a week are normally started with *have*, such as:

- Have a *good* weekend
- Have a *nice* weekend
- etc.

Change the adjective to be what you think most appropriate for the situation.

On the other hand, if you are signing off some correspondence, such as an email, then *Wishing you a happy weekend* is more appropriate.

Similar constructions include

- Wishing you a happy birthday
- Wishing you a merry Christmas
- Wishing you well

To use **Wish you a happy weekend* you need to add *I* to make the sentence grammatical. i.e.

> I wish you a happy weekend.

A notable exception to this is the common postcard sign off *Wish you were here* where it is idiomatic to leave out the *I*.

Answer (score 13):

In the UK we say 'Have a nice weekend.'

Comment: In the US as well. Not sure why someone would downvote this...

Comment: +1. This is what I use as well.

Comment: My guess is the downvoter thought that this doesn't answer the question. But since 4 people have decided it isn't a question, that doesn't apply.

Comment: @Mahnax Another problem with the "doesn't answer the question" rationale is that Jim's answer says about the same thing as Barrie's answer but wasn't downvoted. -- BTW, when I looked at this question an hour ago, I looked all over for a duplicate but didn't find one; the "not a real question" rationale for closing didn't occur to me, nor is it obvious.

Comment: @jwpat7 Hmm, interesting.

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter, but I must say I think *"Have a nice xxxx"* sounds a bit dated/creepy to me. Reminiscent of the dialogue in old b/w movies. Or the vomit-inducing campaigns by retailers enjoining all their staff to say *"Have a nice day!"* to the point it no longer means anything at all. I don't mind *"Have a* **good** *day"*, though.

Answer (score 3):

Having just used/heard this phase for the dozenth time today, I can attest that the common American phrase is "Have a good weekend"  (good, great, etc, depending on what exactly you want to say).